# StepFunctions/Lambda and ECS

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-fargate, aws-step-functions

Here is what I am attempting to do using StepFunctions/Lambda/ECS+Fargate+python+docker

I have a job that is queuing a request and polling to see if the request is complete. Once complete, the file for the request needs to be downloaded. All the above steps, except downloading file is done using Lambda and Choices in Step functions.
[image]

Question: What I need to do is send the JobID from The "Is File Ready?" Choice to the Fargate/ECS Container so that the python script in the container downloads the file and puts it in S3.

Is this the correct thought process: Somehow in the "Is File Ready?" state the output should include the json that the ECSTaskRun can consume? and this json output should have the Job_id as an evn parameter? Once this is done, the python script can read the job_id as env param, os.environ.get('job_id), and do the remaining items?

Or, am I on the wrong track here.

Also I am deploying everything in Python CDK.

Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I would suggest making new question with the of your SF and tasks definition for the new issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass parameters to ECS task in SF, using [Overrides](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-ecs.html) for your task definition. If you want to pass your variables as env variables, you have to overwrite `Environment` in `ContainerOverrides`.

Comment: Hey, for the ECS Run Task, in SF, here is the input that the task gets:                            {
  "Input": "{ \"containerOverrides\": [ { \"name\": \"getFileTask\", \"environment\": [ { \"name\": \"name1\", \"value\": \"123\" }, { \"name\": \"DATE\", \"value\": \"1234-12-12\" }, { \"name\": \"SCRIPT\", \"value\": \"123456\" } ] } ] }"
} However this does not reflect in the containerOverrides section of the container at launch. What am I doing incorrectly? Ty